# Caffe variable batch size

Tags: neural-network, caffe

I know if I have the input layer as follows, my network will take in blobs of dimension `(1,1,100,100)`.

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Input"
  top: "data"
  input_param {
    shape {
      dim: 1
      dim: 1
      dim: 100
      dim: 100
    }
  }
}
```

What should I do to make the first dimension (input batch size) variable? so that I can feed in the network batches of different sizes?

Comment: I think in function `Net<Dtype>::Forward(
    const vector<Blob<Dtype>*> & bottom, Dtype* loss)`, just modify `net_input_blobs_[i]->CopyFrom(*bottom[i]);` to `net_input_blobs_[i]->CopyFrom(*bottom[i], false, true);` can help, which will reshape the input according to the `bottom` blob shape.

Comment: @DaleSong many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reshape the network before calling the `forward()` method. So if you want a variable batch_size, you should reshape the everytime. This can be done in any interface you are using (C, python, MATLAB).

In python, it goes like this:

```
net.blobs['data'].reshape(BATCH_SIZE, CHANNELS, HEIGHT, WIDTH)
net.reshape()
net.forward()
```

hint: I believe `net.reshape()` is optional and the network calls this before executing the forward action.

Comment: I found this a helpful tutorial for caffe: http://christopher5106.github.io/deep/learning/2015/09/04/Deep-learning-tutorial-on-Caffe-Technology.html

Comment: I follow your example but I get errors like: ` Check failed: top[0]->count() == bottom[0]->count() (6656 vs. 11188736) output count must match input count`, do you have any clue what happened?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to AHA's answer, in c++ it's like

```
Blob<float>* input_layer = net_->input_blobs()[0];
input_layer->Reshape(batch_size, input_layer->shape(1), input_layer->shape(2), input_layer->shape(3));
net_->Reshape();
```